# What counts as a 'view'?

Tags: support

What counts as a 'view'?   It can't be a view by unique users because some questions have over 100k views.   I don't think it counts as a view every time you reload a page.   Is it a view per user per day?  Is it a view only after there is an edit, comment or answer?

Comment: A view per user ID/IP, cached for 15 minutes, as explained here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728/162011.

Answer (score 7):

As TARS stated in his comment, a view is basically a [unique IP visit, 15 minutes apart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated). This has been discussed at length on Meta:SE (see below)

As to how some questions have *hundreds of thousands* of views, that's the power of google and the "Hot Network Questions" bar.

---

> I've recently investigated the functioning of the Stack Overflow views
>   counter because I wanted to implement something similar (which I did).
>   My ramblings on the matter are here:
>   [Dissecting the Stack Overflow views counter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/dissecting-the-stack-overflow-views-counter)
>
> So, how that thing works? Quite simply, as I turned out to be.
>
> Every question page has that counter link embedded in it:
>
> ```
> http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3590653/ivc/[Random code]
> ```
>
> which is hit with every page load (either cached or not).
>
> There is some sort of a throttling mechanism in action. It saves the
>   information about a question view per visitor like in pairs:
>
> - for anonymous users, it is `IP + QuestionNr`.
> - for authenticated users it is `UserNr + QuestionNr`.
>
> This information is saved in an expiring cache entry for about 15
>   minutes. If a subsequent hit sees the entry is still there it discards
>   the new hit. If it is already gone it allows for a new record.
>
> Every time a new hit is registered, it is also added to a memory
>   buffer in addition to the expiring cache entry. The buffer itself also
>   expires after a few minutes or after it is filled up to a certain
>   size, whichever happens first. When it expires, everything it has
>   accumulated is written into the database in bulk. They call it a
>   "buffered write scheme". I like the term. Basically the buffer entries
>   are grouped per question and then just added to the sum of the
>   questions views, no particular table to store every visit details (too
>   much to store), like:
>
> ```
> UPDATE Question
> SET Views = Views + @NewViews
> WHERE Nr = 36278
> ```
>
> And the same for every question which has any views registered in the
>   buffer. To optimize and minimize the database access you send the
>   entire data for multiple questions to your update query in one run.
>   You can format the data as XML, join to it inside the query and
>   perform the update in one statement.
>
> That's pretty much it.
>
> I haven't been able to figure out what the [Random code] in the
>   counter url does, but that's okay. Without that mysterious part, I
>   have implemented this scheme under ASP.NET MVC + SQL Server about two
>   weeks ago for a project I'm currently working on. I've got it running
>   on my development machine since then and it's worked like a charm.
>   Views are properly registered as they should. :)